# Creating two lists out of tuple with occasional double value for one list

Tags: python, list, tuples

I am currently working with tuples in Python a came upon this problem:

I have a tuple that looks like this:

```
[("mother", ["Mutter"]), ("and", ["und"]), ("father", ["Vater"]), ("I", ["ich", "mich"]),("not", ["nicht"]), ("at", ["dort", "da"]), ("home", ["Haus", "Zuhause"]), ("now", ["jetzt"])]
```

I need to create two lists, one, where the English words are stored and one, where the German words are stored, but I don't now how, since sometimes there are two German words for one English word.

Is there a nicer way than manually counting through the tuple and storing the words like that?

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Heres a quick and easy way to do it:

```py
wordlist = [("mother", ["Mutter"]), ("and", ["und"]), ("father", ["Vater"]), ("I", ["ich", "mich"]),("not", ["nicht"]), ("at", ["dort", "da"]), ("home", ["Haus", "Zuhause"]), ("now", ["jetzt"])]

english = []
german = []

for pair in wordlist:
  english.append(pair[0])
  for item in pair[1]: german.append(item)

print(english)
print(german)
```

Comment: nice your answer really helped!!   But is there a way to store the German translations, if there a two for one word, in two separated lists?

Comment: im not entirely sure i understand that question, but the code below should do what I think you want:

wordlist = [("mother", ["Mutter"]), ("and", ["und"]), ("father", ["Vater"]), ("I", ["ich", "mich"]),("not", ["nicht"]), ("at", ["dort", "da"]), ("home", ["Haus", "Zuhause"]), ("now", ["jetzt"])]

english = []
german = []

for pair in wordlist:
  english.append(pair[0])
  german.append(pair[1])

print(english)
print(german)

Comment: I meant it more in way that you have three lists in the end with:  englisch =['mother', 'and', 'father', 'I', 'not', 'at', 'home', 'now']; germanOne = ['Mutter', 'und', 'Vater', 'ich', 'nicht', 'dort', 'da', 'Haus', 'jetzt'] germanTwo = ['mich', 'Zuhause']

Comment: Ah i see, i will make a edit in the main answer

Answer (score 0):

you need to iterate through the list, and save the first element of that iterator in english list and save second element of that iterator in the german list using append and extend .

```
x = [("mother", ["Mutter"]), ("and", ["und"]), ("father", ["Vater"]), ("I", ["ich", "mich"]),("not", ["nicht"]), ("at", ["dort", "da"]), ("home", ["Haus", "Zuhause"]), ("now", ["jetzt"])]
english, german = [], []
for a, b in x:
    english.append(a)
    german.extend(b)
 
print(english, german)
# ['mother', 'and', 'father', 'I', 'not', 'at', 'home', 'now'] ['Mutter', 'und', 'Vater', 'ich', 'mich', 'nicht', 'dort', 'da', 'Haus', 'Zuhause', 'jetzt']
```